# Copy Constructor On Base Class Not Optimized Away

Tags: c++, optimization, iterator

I was looking at the disassembly for my iterator class, shown below, which was compiled with maximum compiler optimizations.

```
class MY_ITR : public std::iterator< std::forward_iterator_tag, MY_TYPE* > {
public:
    MY_ITR();
    MY_ITR(const MY_TYPE2*, int);

    // standard iterator impl

private:
    static const int N = 3;
    int m_data[N];
};
```

I noticed an extra function call that looked like a copy constructor.  Sure enough, after some digging, I discovered that someone modified the std::_Iterator_Base class to include an empty constructor, copy constructor, and assignment operator (?!?!).  At the time this edit was made (a long time ago), it was to circumvent a warning in a code checking tool.

```
namespace std {
struct _Iterator_Base {
    _Iterator_Base() {}
    _Iterator_Base(const _Iterator_Base& rhs) {}
    _Iterator_Base& operator =(const _Iterator_Base& rhs) { return *this; }
};

template <...>
struct iterator : _Iterator_Base {
    // typedefs
};

...
```

Removing the implementation of _Iterator_Base causes the extra function call to disappear.  I know that default implementation of MY_ITR's copy constructor needs to call the copy constructor of _Iterator_Base, but I can't for the life of me figure out why the compiler couldn't optimize it away.

Comment: You should: 1. Clarify what is exactly your question (add it at the end of your post, in bold, if necessary) . . . 2. Give us the platform, compiler and its version (and possibly, the STL version, if not native for that compiler) . . .